# SQLKata Inner Join using LEFT string function

Tags: c#, sql-server, inner-join, sqlkata

I am trying to write the following query using SQLKata for SQLServer:

`SELECT Company FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON LEFT(Table1.[Company], 5) = LEFT(Table2.accountName, 5)`

I have tried the following:

```
        var db = new QueryFactory(connection, compiler);


        var query = db.Query("Table1")
            .Join("Table2", "LEFT([Table1].[Company],5)", "LEFT([Table2].[accountName],5)")
            .Select("Company").Get();
```

But the fails with the error 'The multi-part identifier could not be bound'.

It appears there is no JoinRaw that I can use in sqlKata either.  Does anyone know if there is a way i can create a Left string function in sql kata and use in queries like the one above?

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and run query.  The error messages are much better in SSMS and same command text query will run in SSMS.  It appears the two tables in the database cannot be joined.  It is possible one is an integer and the other a string.  It could be a typo that the column names are not spelled correctly.  SSMS will give the exact type of error.

Comment: The sql statement that I copied above works in SSMS.  What I am trying to do is recreate this statement in SQLKata.  I don't know if that is possible because I don't know if there is a way to create a LEFT() string function in SQLKata, that is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: It looks like you are using entity where there are classes that map to the database.  So I do not know why you Join is using strings instead of the db class properties.

Comment: I am not using Entity Framework.  I am using SQLKata.

Comment: I do not know SQLKata very well.  I would recommend breaking your query into multiple parts and make sure each part does not return a null.  See the SQLKata documentation :  https://sqlkata.com/docs/join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Sqlkata expect column names as string inside the **Join** method arguments, without any wrapper or functions, the reason is to prevent SQL injection, so expressions are not allowed here.

for such cases you can use the **FromRaw** method (See https://sqlkata.com/docs/from#from-a-raw-expression).

```
db.Query().FromRaw("[Table1] JOIN [Table2] LEFT([Table1].[Company],5) ON LEFT([Table2].[AccountName],5)")
```

In the coming version you can inject **RawExpression** for such cases but this is not officially released yet.

```
db.Query("Table1").Join(
  "Table2", 
  Raw("Left([Table1].[Company], 5)"), 
  Raw("Left([Table2].[AccountName], 5)")
)
```

In a side note, performing a join based on an evaluated expression is not recommended and may lead to performance issues.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know why I didn''t think to use FromRaw.